# "Great Divide" synonyms

Tags: expressions, synonyms, poetry

I am looking for strong, yet poetic expressions/synonyms of "Great Divide" which, beside its other meanings, expresses *"a major point of division, especially **death.**"*

The context I need is the act of parting (death) by lovers presented as a strong, sad and dramatic act.

**Example:** *They tasted each other's lips for the very last time and closed their Great Divide.*

Comment: Are you looking for something which expresses the parting of two people (for example husband and wife) by the death of one, which is a division; or what might be experienced by the one who has died, in *crossing* the division between life and death? *The Great Divide* covers both, but something like Josh's *fearful passage* only the latter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgot to add explanation. I am looking for an expression of death, but especially, as you said, " the parting of two people" (lovers). But if there's any poetic/obsolete/archaic verb referring such meaning, I am looking forward to adding it in my vocabulary. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question rather than leaving important data in comments? An example sentence with a gap in it for the synonym would probably be useful. And maybe even a note on why "the Great Divide" is not useful (too clichéd, too geographical, whatever) as that will give some idea of what to avoid.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I've tried to give a precise insight of what I'm looking for as much as I could. Please, feel free to edit it if it's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

[Passage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Passage)  has been used in literature to convey the idea:

> - Death.

**The fearful passage:**

> - of their death marked love *was stated through the tragic story of Romeo and Juliet.* This is a sad love story. The saying means that they loved each other so much that they killed themselves because they both feared not being able to live without the other person.

Answer (score 2):

How about **Schism**?

[Definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schism)

> noun
>
> 1. division or disunion, especially into mutually opposed parties.
> 2. the parties so formed.
> 3. Ecclesiastical
>
> a. a formal division within, or separation from, a church or religious body over some doctrinal difference.
>
> b. the state
> of a sect or body formed by such division.
>
> c. the offense of causing
> or seeking to cause such a division.

Comment: Hi Ronan, how does 'Schism' relate to the death that divides two lovers?

Comment: Poetic licence? "The context I need is the act of parting (death) by lovers presented as a strong, sad and dramatic act." There are few more dramatic partings than a schism.